# How to add an array to store items?

Tags: java

I am new to java and am writing a program for class that I have to modify so that it can handle multiple items and I need to use an array to store the items. This is what I have so far.

```
public class ProductDVD
    {
    private String productName;
    private int productID;
    private long unitsInStock;
    private float unitPrice;

public void setName( String productName )
    {
    this.productName = productName;
    }

public void setProductID( int productID )
    {
    this.productID = productID;
    }

public void setUnitsInStock( long unitsInStock )
    {
    this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    }

public void setUnitPrice( float unitPrice )
    {
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
    return productName;
    }

    public int getProductID()
    {
    return productID;
    }

    public long getUnitsInStock()
    {
    return unitsInStock;
    }

    public float getUnitPrice()
    {
    return unitPrice;
    }

    public float getInventoryValue()
    {
    return( unitsInStock * unitPrice );
    }
    }


import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DVDinventory
    {
    public static void main( String args [] )
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    ProductDVD dvd = new ProductDVD();

    System.out.print( "Enter a DVD Title: " );
    dvd.setName( input.nextLine() );

    System.out.print( "Enter the Product ID: " );
    dvd.setProductID( input.nextInt()); 

    System.out.print( "Enter the Product's Unit Price: " );
    dvd.setUnitPrice( input.nextFloat() );

    System.out.print( "Enter the Number of Units in Stock: " );
    dvd.setUnitsInStock( input.nextLong() );

    input.nextLine();

    System.out.println( "Name:          " + dvd.getName() );
    System.out.println( "ID:            " + dvd.getProductID() );
    System.out.println( "Unit Price:        " + dvd.getUnitPrice() );
    System.out.println( "Units in Stock:        " + dvd.getUnitsInStock() );
    System.out.println( "Inventory Value:   " + dvd.getInventoryValue() );
    }
    }
```

The question is how do I create an array that can hold both string and int elements? I need the array to hold the DVD name, id, unit price, units in stock, and total inventory value.

Comment: what is the question? what array do you want to create? what do you want it to hold?

Comment: You didn't ask a question and we're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: sorry, the question is how do I create an array that can hold both string and int elements? I need the array to hold the DVD name, id, unit price, units in stock, and total inventory value.

Answer (score 2):

Using a java.util.Collection would make more sense, but if you HAVE to use an array for your homework:

```
private static int INVENTORY_SIZE = 42; //that's what you mean by total inventory value, right?

ProductDVD[] dvds = new ProductDVD[INVENTORY_SIZE];

Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

for (int i = 0; i < INVENTORY_SIZE; i++) {
    dvds[i] = new ProductDVD();  
    //your code to read in data here...
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, could you tell me for my own knowledge what part of the for loop seperates the string and int input elements?

Comment: @markus: you're missing the obvious: don't store ints and strings in your array. Store ProductDVDs. You already have the code to read the information and create a ProductDVD instance. Now you just have to put this ProductDVD in an array of ProductDVD.

Comment: JB Nizet is right: you have to think in Objects. So in your code to read in data, you now write dvds[i].setName instead of dvd.setName. I further suggest you read up about object oriented programming, e.g. on wikipedia or [in the Sun, I mean Oracle, tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Look [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) as start point.